# Correctly format the jQuery .load function when using a response first

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, response

I can't figure out how to correctly format the `.load` function with what I'm doing.

Everything works fine if I provide the URL but cant get it working without errors when using the response first.

Here is what works:

```
$("#postholder #" +response.postid).load("viewbuild.php?id=22 #" +response.postid, function() {
```

But instead of giving the URL directly, I want to use a URL that I return.

So ideally something like this:

```
$("#postholder #" +response.postid).load(response.pageurl "#" +response.postid, function() {
```

I have also tried this:

```
$("#postholder #" +response.postid).load(response.pageurl + "#" +response.postid, function() {
```

Which works in a sense, but doesn't load the specified div. Instead simply loads the whole page.

But that doesn't work of course. Can anyone just give me the way I should be doing this?

Comment: You have forgotten a '+'. Should be: `$("#postholder #" +response.postid).load(response.pageurl + "#" + response.postid, function() {`

Comment: just updated the question, have tried this but it loads the whole page when doing it like this and doesn't load the specified div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the working example there are a space between the url and the hashtag(#)/id. Try:

```
$("#postholder #" +response.postid).load(response.pageurl + " #" +response.postid, function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing + sign

```
$("#postholder #" +response.postid).load(response.pageurl + "#" +response.postid, function() {});
```

**Updated**

So in that case you can try the following first load all the html then get your specfic div using find as follow

```
$("#postholder #" +response.postid).load(response.pageurl, function() {});

var divHtml =$("#postholder #" +response.postid).find("#" +response.postid);
```

Comment: just updated the question, have tried this but it loads the whole page when doing it like this and doesn't load the specified div.

Comment: see my updated answer you can load while html then can find your specified div

Comment: Thanks for the edit, however the answer i just marked as correct spotted a space in the working example which worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I have the same answer without having space so thats mean i was correct at this time..:-)